# How to create a colour border in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, borders

I am making a poster with Inkscape (version 0.9.1 Ubuntu). I would like to make a simple border with a specific colour and width.

What I have done previously in other applications such as LibreOffice Draw is to create an object as a group of rectangles which reproduces the border. I would prefer to edit the page properties instead of add objects to the page.

The only way I can think to do this right now is to add a base layer to the page, group four rectangles onto it in the shape of the border and then add transparent layers to that. I would like to avoid this though.

Comment: Can you please expand your question with what you have tried and where you are having issues?

Comment: Welcome to the site.  We do not mind helping you at all but we require some effort in a question.  We are not a tutorial board we are a Q&A website for specific questions that can in fact be answered.  We do not create tutorials either.  If you can make an [edit] with effort I will be more than happy to re-open your question so we could assist you.

Comment: Draw a box, pick a stroke color, pick a stroke width.

Comment: draw a box using the Create Rectangle tool, or F4. Then Ctrl+Shift+F will bring up the Fill and Stroke Panel. Set the Fill to "No Paint" (the X on the left of the Fill tab). Now switch to the Stroke Paint tab and select the color. Then switch to the Stroke Style tab and select your width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SVG standard does not have a concept of a "page" border like other programs you mentioned. The only way to do this with an SVG--and thus Inkscape--is to draw a rectangle for your border. Drawing a separate shape in Libreoffice instead of using a style's border settings would be bad practice--in SVG, it is not.

You can use the snapping feature in Inkscape to snap the cursor to the corners of objects (or the page itself) to make it easier to get the border in the correct spot. This site is not for tutorials on learning to use software though. Take a look at [this tutorial from the Inkscape website](https://inkscape.org/en/doc/tutorials/shapes/tutorial-shapes.en.html) for basic information on drawing.

Generally, when I want a border around something, I work on all the objects in that area, draw the border, and then group them together with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> so they can be moved around.

Comment: Link is dead...

Answer (score 0):

It's possible when you open an existing SVG file -- created in an earlier version of Inkscape or possibly from some other application -- that there is no "page border", even when you try to set one.

When creating a new document, you will get a "page border" in the default view:

[image: Inkscape new document]

You can copy/paste objects from other SVG files into it, and the "page border" remains. This "border" can be customized: select the object, then use `File > Document Properties... > Page [tab]` to control the size, display, behaviour, and "look" of the border:

[image: Page border control]

Using the "Resize page to content..." drop-down (must be toggled) allows you to ... resize the "page border" to the drawing or selection. There is also a wide selection of pre-sets for this space, as the above screenshot also demonstrates.

For OP's scenario, a "border" can be drawn, and then the Document Properties used to resize the "page" to this border/rectangle. The edges will be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

## Step 1: Draw a border

[image]

## Step 2: Resize page

Go to File > Document Properties:

[image]

## Result

[image]